# Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have question regarding to 
Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse RJG-00007
Is there known some issues/limitations to work  with Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse RJG-00007 on Windows 7 ? 
On Microsoft site [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/accessories/products/mice/microsoft-ergonomic-mouse?activetab=overview:primaryr3)
mentioned that : **Compatibility -- Microsoft Windows 10/8.1/7**
But several lines later : **PC must meet these requirements to download: Microsoft Windows 10/8**.1

The question is : did anyone tried to install/work with this mouse on Windows 7 ? Is there issues / limitations ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Did anyone tried to install/work with this mouse on Windows 7?

**A version of [Mouse and Keyboard Center 2.3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42510) absolutely supports Windows 7.  However, `Mouse and Keyboard Center 2.3` does not support the Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse, all that means is you will be unable to use the programmable buttons on the mouse.**  [Mouse and Keyboard Center 12](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051843/accessories-mouse-keyboard-center-download) does not support Windows 7, which is the required version, based on Microsoft's own [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051843/accessories-mouse-keyboard-center-download).

> Are there issues/limitations?

The software is only required to program the programmable buttons on the mouse.

Source:

- [Which devices are supported by Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034170/which-devices-are-supported-by-microsoft-mouse-and-keyboard-center)
- [Mouse and Keyboard Center download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051843/accessories-mouse-keyboard-center-download)